# Get AD Email Address From SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory, openrowset

I am Domain Admin and am trying to use `OpenRowset` to query AD from `Sql Server 2008` this is my syntax (and it is probably a syntax error) but I get this error:

> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   An error occurred while preparing the query 
> "SELECT name, displayname, givenname, distinguishedName, SAMAccountName
>   
> FROM 'LDAP://Domainname.company.com/ou=northamerica,
>         dc=domainname,dc=company,dc=com' 
>       
> WHERE Name = 'Red*'" 
> for execution against OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "(null)".

And this is my syntax I try to run

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject', 'adsdatasource',
'SELECT name, displayname, givenname, distinguishedName, SAMAccountName
FROM ''LDAP://Domainname.company.com/ou=northamerica,
  dc=domainname,dc=company,dc=com'' 
WHERE Name = ''Red*''')
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this a while back and I was getting results. See if this gets you in a right path.

```
SELECT cn, objectGUID
FROM  'LDAP://xxx.local/OU=xxx Users,DC=xxx,DC=xxx'
WHERE objectClass = 'User' AND cn = 'John Smith'
```

Comment: What should go with the xx.local, should that be my Domain name?